# Yii2 - Create and use a temporary mysql table in GridView

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, temp-tables

I need to create and use a temporary mysql table in *Yii2's GridView*.

My GridView shows some columns from table `license` with one additional column that is computed at runtime. I can do this easily (using property transformation in the model), however, I need sorting / filtering as well. I've resolved this in the past using views or temporary tables.

I have ported the column value calculation to *SQL* (to use it in a temporary table), but I don't know how to do all this in Yii2. The reason I want to use a temporary table and not a view is that the column value calculation depends on runtime configuration of the application.

I have not found any documentation or examples on how to do this in *Yii2*. Are there any out there? Maybe someone here has done a similar thing and can post some sample code?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** This is my temporary table I'm trying to use with GridView. I need filtering and sorting by *status* field. Right now it's a view but since some parameters depend on application runtime configuration, it will have to be a temporary table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW extended_license AS
SELECT
    license.*,
    (CASE
        -- license expired
        WHEN (license.valid_until_date < UTC_DATE())
            THEN 'License Expired'

        -- support valid until year_month(begin_date) + 1year <= year_month(today).
        WHEN (license.branding_name IN ('this_is_runtime_generated_list'))
            THEN CASE ( Year(license_begin_date) + 1 < Year(UTC_DATE())
                    OR (Year(license_begin_date) + 1 = Year(UTC_DATE()) AND Month(license_begin_date) <= Month(UTC_DATE)) )
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Support Expired'
                ELSE 'Valid'
            END

        -- support valid if major version is current year
        WHEN (license.branding_name IN ('this_is_runtime_generated_list'))
            THEN CASE (license.program_major_ver != YEAR(UTC_DATE()))
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Support Expired'
                ELSE 'Valid'
            END
        -- support valid
        ELSE 'Valid'
    END) AS status
FROM license;
```

Comment: why not use a custom field by declaring into the model and using it as the additional column that is computed via query?

Comment: take a look a these sample http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

Comment: @scaisEdge pointed in the right direction

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam  i hope ..  if the OP post a pratical sample should be better

Comment: yes i agree that would have triggered the process of solving much faster @scaisEdge

Comment: i couldn't guess what you pointed out maybe if the code was there.....

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam   but seems that ths question interests only for us.. it may be a time zone problem with the OP. we'll see if there are any comments later

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated the original post with SQL table/view I want to use for the GridView.
The wiki link you posted looks interesting, but I'm not sure if I'm able to use my field value calculation logic like that.

Comment: P.S. Yes, it's a timezone issue :)

Comment: Ok .. but as you create a temp table you could is the same moment create a view  too .. so why not use a view and a model based on this view  .. in this way all functionaties related  to ActiverRecord  ara available for your DataProvider and gridview ...

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm not sure re-creating a view on each request is a good idea. Especially if someone else is selecting from it. There's also the access rights issue (I may not have permission to modify the schema). This is what temporary tables are for. I was hoping to create a temporary table on index page access and have the model based on it.

Comment: then also the temp table is bad idea .... but remember that the view don't store result  .. just store the code for select the data when you invoke the  view name  .. so the view return always .. fresh result  ..  and a model based on the voew ensure valid  fresh data

Comment: I'm not sure you know what temporary tables are for. They are per-connection views, basically SELECTs that provide a temporary view that is destroyed on connection end.
The views, on the other hand, require database schema modification (along with proper permissions). MySQL schema modifications are not transactional, so you can't expect to safely re-create a view while another connection is reading from it.